# how to include Authtimeout in PHP

Tags: php, rest, api, authentication

I am working in `REST API` using `Codeigniter` PHP and using `jwt` token I just want that to include timeout in authentication, means if the user does not do some activity for 1 minute then he should logout/accessToken become null, How can I do this? Here is my code which checking authentication of the user for every request, but how can I add timeout?

```
private function auths($token,$userType,$usersId)
    {
        $users['rec'] = $this->Model_users->checkAuth($token,$userType,$usersId);
        //$users['rec'] getting query result (whether token existing in databse or not )
        if($users['rec']!="")
            {
                return;
            }
        else
            {
                $responseJSON = array("Status" => false,"Result" => "AccessToken not matched");
                header("content-type:application/json");
                $response = json_encode($responseJSON);
                echo $response;
                exit;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the entire session to terminate after 1 minute (or just a certain session variable)??

If it is the entire session and all variables, then you can use

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60); //Set the time in seconds
```

After 60 seconds of session inactivity this will timeout the session